# How to set attributes as unsafe in RESTful Yii2?

Tags: rest, yii2

I have a controller in Yii2 that extends ActiveController to be RESTful and I can update it OK using the PUT method. However I would like to set some attributes as unsafe as I don't want them to be updatable.

Reading some different examples I thought I would be able to do something like this in the model's rules:

```
[['first_name','last_name','!password'], 'safe', 'on' => 'update'],
```

However this doesn't prevent password being updated.

So then I found the scenarios() method and thought this should work:

```
public function scenarios()
{
    return [
        'default' => ['*'], // Also tried without this line
        'update' => ['first_name','last_name','!password'],
    ];
}
```

But that prevents all attributes getting updated.

Does anyone have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

This rule would just mean that the attributes can be massivly assigned (using [Model::load()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-model.html#load%28%29-detail)), however, without any validation and also in each scenario.

```
[['first_name','last_name','password'], 'safe'],
```

But you can use here also e.g. 'string' instead of 'safe'. Then it is also used in each scenario but now with string validation.

With the following you introduce an 'update' scenario and you tell the Validation engine that first_name and last_name should be massively assignable and get validated, but password is excluded from that. Like you have expected.

```
public function scenarios()
{
    return [
        'update' => ['first_name','last_name','!password'],
    ];
}
```

Important is also that you set the scenario on update or creation (in the controller) before you call load() or save():

```
$model = ...
$model->scenario = 'update';
$model->load(...);
$model->save();
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. As the controller extends ActiveController to be RESTful, I do not have an actionUpdate() method as RESTful Yii handles this in the background. I was hoping to not have to overwrite the update method just to control which values can be assigned.

Comment: @Dubby In your example you have used scenario based validation rules. You have to define which scenario has to be used explicitly before load and save. What you could do: set [ActiveController::$updateScenario](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-rest-activecontroller.html#$updateScenario-detail) or you could overwrite [UpdateAction](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-rest-updateaction.html). But overwriting the controller to alter the action is quite usual ([doc])(http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-controllers.html#customizing-actions).