# Restrict certain attributes from updating Yii2

Tags: rest, yii2

I am making a REST API using Yii2. In Put request method during update i want to restrict user to not able to update his/her email address. Is there a way that we can achieve this? Right now when user send put request with changed email address the email address gets changed.

Comment: this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30372778/how-to-set-attributes-as-unsafe-in-restful-yii2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use model scenarios [See Model Scenarios](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-models.html)

Model

```
namespace app\models;

use yii\db\ActiveRecord;

class User extends ActiveRecord
{
    const SCENARIO_API = 'API';
    const SCENARIO_OTHER = 'OTHER';

    public function scenarios()
    {
        return [
            self::SCENARIO_API => ['username', 'password'],
            self::SCENARIO_OTHER => ['username', 'email', 'password'],
        ];
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
namespace app\controllers;
use yii\rest\ActiveController;
use app\models\User;

class UserController extends ActiveController
{
    public $modelClass = 'app\models\User';
    public $createScenario = User::SCENARIO_API;
}
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Thankyou. Just a little modification in the model. it should be  public $updateScenario rather then  public $createScenario.